# Type error on using Apache Kakfa's KafkaConsumer api

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Im writing a simple Kafka Consumer class as follows

```
public class MySimpleKafkaConsumer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("group.id", "mygroup");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("storm-test-topic"));
```

.
.

Although I get an error at the below line stating

> The method subscribe(String...) in the type
>   KafkaConsumer is not applicable for the arguments
>   (List)

```
consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("storm-test-topic"));
```

This seems correct as per the api docs. 
Here is the dependency version

```
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0.1</version>
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: Is there any possibility you did not reference org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer? There is no such a method signature defined in o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer

Comment: @amesthystic. The problem was indeed in the dependency name. Thanks. I was able to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

The method needs a `String...` parameter. That's not compatible with `List<String>`, only `String[]`. It's a feature of how Java handles var-arg function parameters.

Just call it with a single String, i.e. String[1]

```
consumer.subscribe("storm-test-topic");
```

Answer (score 0):

calling it as below resolved the error :

```
consumer.subscribe("storm-test-topic");
```

Answer (score 0):

The reference for the KafkaConsumer and the arrays should point to `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer` and `java.util.Arrays` respectively.